# Como puedo usar listas como parametro de una clase?

Tags: c++, array, lista, poo, diseño-de-clases

Estoy intentando usar una clase para imprimir un atributo de la misma mediante un método. Este atributo es definido en el momento de instanciar la clase. Sin embargo, el resultado es totalmente diferente al que se le envía al constructor. ¿Puede que la naturaleza del problema sea que el parámetro es un array y existen complicaciones con la memoria?

Código :

```
class prueva{

    public:
        int num[3];
        
        prueva(int num[3]);
        void mostrar();
    
};


prueva :: prueva(int num[3]){

    this->num[3] = num[3];
};

void prueva :: mostrar(){
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << this->num[i] << " ";    
    };
    
    
};


int main(){

    int lis[3] = {5,4,7};
    
    prueva objeto(lis);
    
    objeto.mostrar();

    return 0; 
}
```

output:

4200134 0 4748656

Answer (score 1):

Esto:

```
this->num[3] = num[3];
```

No hace lo que crees. Crees que estás igualando una formación<sup>1</sup> de tres enteros a otra formación de tres enteros, lo que en realidad está haciendo es igualar el cuarto elemento<sup>2</sup> de una formación al cuarto elemento de otra formación.

En resumen, confundes el funcionamiento de formaciones con el funcionamiento de objetos; una formación es una colección de objetos y no puedes (en general) copiarlas con una instrucción de igualación (`=`), debes usar un bucle:

```
prueva :: prueva(int num[3]){

    for (int indice = 0; indice != 3; ++indice)
        this->num[indice] = num[indice];

} // No necesita ';' al final.
```

Si quieres el tipo de comportamiento que estabas usando, puedes usar un objeto `std::array` en lugar de una formación:

```
class prueva {

    public:
        std::array<int, 3> num;

    // Referencia constante para evitar copias
    prueva(const std::array<int, 3> &num) {
        this->num = num;
    }
    // Bucle for de rango, mas comodo de usar y mas legible
    void mostrar() {
        for (const auto &n : num)
            std::cout << n << ' ';
    }
};
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNasMwEIXX0ikGCo0NTlNoS8FxvegReoOxPElVbMnoJxCCz@6O5OBuOgshPUnzvXlqmvZqQHNelgdt1BB7gkZbHxzh2Mo/DZ3DayslP/YeJhfpgnCTErim2A1a1Xmfyoe@rvOHRptQwUsLJo5HKcXhAF90IkdGaQRljQ9oAsGEDoEuOqBjddLot2Yrqshv/@v8yK1LdiJE@NZ@3/IRPlaemDPxM6qB4GQd8CCOZ7UVjOgZNNreJjF65l6zONBZdwNt@IvVPYwpEHTFykmd7n4wBssOoE7Aku9EdqhsDNA0YNKyg122MnMAbJop2hQlRyfuKdruh4Itbm/Va/U@l8fMlmKVnzZ2ys9RiM7A8xHkvCy/)</kbd>.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

###### <sup>2</sup>Las formaciones se indexan desde cero.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar la siguiente parte del codigo:

```
prueva :: prueva(int num[3]){

this->num[3] = num[3];

};
```

Por esta:

```
prueva :: prueva(int num[3]){

this->num[0] = num[0];

this->num[1] = num[1];

this->num[2] = num[2];

};
```